# Is there a Python slice notation equivalent for (i+1)%N?

Tags: python, slice

I have a Python numpy array that I am using for a simulation with toroidal boundary conditions.

For example, at the boundary when `i = N-1`, `i+1` becomes 0.

I am using `a[(i+1)%N, (j+1)%N]` for accessing nearest neighbors so the index automatically wraps around.

Just wondering if there's a faster way to do this, using the Python/Numpy slicing syntax.

Comment: You might be able to drop the `+1`. But is this really too slow, and are you sure the indexing is the bottleneck?

Comment: No, I don't know if it's a bottleneck - just curious if there is another way to do this.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951020/pythonic-circular-list

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of Python's negative indexing.

```
a[(i+1)-N, (j+1)-N]
```

is equivalent to your version using modulo. Proof:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[(i+1)%len(a)], a[i+1-len(a)])


2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
1 1
```

If the boundaries are smaller than the lengths of the axes of the array, you could take a slice of the array with the right boundaries (which shouldn't use too much memory in numpy, as it will just be a view into the original array) and then use the negative indexing method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with some similar to:

```
n = 10
a = range(n)
for i in range(n):
   print a[i-1],a[i],a[i-(n-1)]
```

I don't know the performance "+-" vs "%", but I believe that is faster than with %.