# Slice a list based on an index and items behind it in Python

Tags: python, list

Say I have an array of degree values, like this:

```
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]
```

I would pick an angle and then be able to bisect this hypothetical circle in order to make it easier to find the shortest route to the target direction.

Saying that, how can I pick a specific value, like `90`, and then be able to find the previous 12 elements behind that, including the index wrapping around to the end?

So, taking that earlier value and applying to that list, I would get something like this:

```
[90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

Using slice notation, I tried doing this:

```
index = DEGREES.index(90)
print(DEGREES[index-12:index]) # start 12 values back, stop at index
```

But this only prints an empty array.

Is there a way to slice a list so I can get the 12 previous values behind the index I'm using?

**EDIT:**

This turned out to be an XY Problem, my bad. Originally, I was trying to create a smooth rotation system in Pygame, with my attempts to calculate angles not working, I asked this question to solve a problem with yet another idea I was trying to implement. I ended up accepting the answer that helped me set up the smooth rotation system, but there are relevant answers to the original question below that.

Comment: This might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951020/pythonic-circular-list

Comment: The dupe is wrong. In the question of the dupe it specifically states that he wants to `grab the index of an arbitrary element and the values of its neighbors`. Which is a clearly different question

Comment: Is `DEGREES` just an example or will you only use this slicing with increasing values and a constant increment?

Comment: What Eric Duminil is likely getting at is that there's no need to construct such a list if you're just incrementing by a constant value. This list could just as easily be represented by something like `range(0,360,15)` and you could calculate the information you're after on the fly: `[i%360 for i in range(90,90-15*13,-15)]`

Comment: @zephyr: [Exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136669/6419007)

Comment: @EricDuminil This array of degrees is designed to work with a smooth rotation system that I'm trying to create in pygame. Normally I would just find the difference between the current direction and the target direction and increment from there, but since the rotation rolls over at zero I have to hardcode the values to make sure that it will always go the shortest route possible. Its a bit more complex than that but to keep a concise question I left why I'm doing this out.

Comment: @Pygasm: You really should mention what your actual goal is in the question (not just in comments) because otherwise you might get many answers which miss the point. I dare say that my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136669/6419007)  will help you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Arithmetic with angles

Your goal isn't to slice, concatenate or reverse lists. Your goal is to do basic arithmetic with degrees and keep the results between `0` and `359`. For this, you *really* should use the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator [`%`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
>>> 90 % 360
90
>>> 390 % 360
30
>>> -60 % 360
300
>>> 360 % 360
0
```

## Back to the question

If you only want to use this slicing for degrees with a constant increment, you could generate the desired list directly:

```
>>> STEP = 15
>>> list(range(0, 360, STEP))
[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345]
>>> def previous_degrees(start, n, step=STEP):
...     return [(start - i * step) % 360 for i in range(n + 1)]
... 
>>> previous_degrees(90, 12)
[90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
>>> previous_degrees(90, 12, 30)
[90, 60, 30, 0, 330, 300, 270, 240, 210, 180, 150, 120, 90]
>>> previous_degrees(90, 6, 45)
[90, 45, 0, 315, 270, 225, 180]
```

## Your real question

You wrote in a comment:

> This array of degrees is designed to work with a smooth rotation
>   system that I'm trying to create in pygame. Normally I would just find
>   the difference between the current direction and the target direction
>   and increment from there, but since the rotation rolls over at zero I
>   have to hardcode the values to make sure that it will always go the
>   shortest route possible.

From two angles, you need to determine if you should turn clockwise or anticlockwise. You can use modulo again to make sure that the rotation will be between -180° and 179°:

```
def shortest_rotation(start_angle, end_angle):
    return (end_angle - start_angle + 180) % 360 - 180
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> shortest_rotation(0, 90)
90
>>> shortest_rotation(90, 0)
-90
>>> shortest_rotation(90, 90)
0
>>> shortest_rotation(90, 330)
-120
>>> shortest_rotation(0, 180)
-180
>>> shortest_rotation(0, 181)
-179
>>> shortest_rotation(0, 179)
179
>>> shortest_rotation(10, 350)
-20
```

You can now create a list of angles, turning in the shortest direction:

```
def rotation_steps(start_angle, end_angle, n):
    increment = shortest_rotation(start_angle, end_angle) / n
    return [(start_angle + i * increment) % 360 for i in range(n + 1)]
```

As an example:

```
>>> rotation_steps(90, 270, 12)
[90.0, 75.0, 60.0, 45.0, 30.0, 15.0, 0.0, 345.0, 330.0, 315.0, 300.0, 285.0, 270.0]
>>> rotation_steps(10, 350, 2)
[10.0, 0.0, 350.0]
```

The list uses float in order to avoid missing the `end_angle` if `increment` isn't an integer.

Comment: This feels a lot more elegant than the other solutions I'm seeing, I'll try it today and then come back if it works or not. I do apologize that I didn't exactly include why I wanted this system in the first place, I felt like I was going to be downvoted/ignored if I tried to explain further than the basic premise of the problem.

Comment: @Pygasm Don't worry, it's hard to write a good question, and it's hard to include enough information yet not write too long a question. See [*XY Problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/390071).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much, I'll try to not make an XY problem next time.

Comment: @Pygasm My pleasure! Please update your question with the comment in which you explain your real goal. Comments can be deleted more easily than questions.

Answer (score 18):

Or you could use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

dq = deque(reversed((0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345)))

index = dq.index(90)
dq.rotate(-index)
res = list(islice(dq, 13))
# [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

You could use that as a function:

```
def f(i):
    dq.rotate(-dq.index(i))
    return list(islice(dq, 13))

#  f(90) = [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

Answer (score 11):

Something like this might be more direct:

```
index = DEGREES.index(90)
print([DEGREES[i] for i in range(index, index-13, -1)])
```

Answer (score 7):

For these cases, a NumPy function that comes in handy is [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), which, as its name specifies, rolls the elements in the array, and as also as mentioned in the documentation:

> Elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at the first

Which is exactly what we need in order to roll at the back the first items in the list up to the index where `90` appears.

So one approach could be to use the index where `90` appears using the `index` list method, and shift the array up to `-k` positions, `k` being the given index. Then we can just slice the list and take its last `n` elements reversed:

```
import numpy as np

l = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]

def roll_n_reversed(l, i, n):
    return np.roll(l, -l.index(i)-1)[:-(n+1):-1]

roll_n_reversed(l, 90, 13)
```

Which yields the expected output:

```
array([ 90,  75,  60,  45,  30,  15,   0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270])
```

Comment: if it's not a sorted array , don't you think in that case it will fail ?

Comment: Updated the solution @prashantrana now it works without assuming the array is sorted

Comment: Hmm @EricDuminil I did have the `l.index(90)` inside the key arg which was a mistake, should scale linearly now

Comment: It looks better now. Sorting probably isn't needed but there's not much difference between `O(n.log n)` and `O(n)` anyway.

Comment: Yes well the whole idea is to simply rearange based on whether an item is bellow `l.index(90)` or not. Then its just a matter of slicing. Thanks for pointing out @EricDuminil

Comment: i don;t know, but  why dont just create a new list where reverse of list (all element upto 90 ) and reverse of list (from 90 + next value to end ) and from this final list just get the first 12 element, no need to sort (op didn't mentioned sort need if need then fter sort use like this ) with sort (O(N)) else O(n)

Comment: @yatu not doubting your answer, what I want to say for the given OP problem, instead of sorting and then doing the extra operation and then giving result, by doing sicing is better , and let us save time and computation

Answer (score 7):

An [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) ([`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)) based solution:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

DEGREES = cycle(reversed((
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345)))

next(item for item in DEGREES if item == 90)  # advance to next 90
res = [90] + list(islice(DEGREES, 12))
# [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

You can pack that into a one-liner function:

```
def f(i):
    return [next(d for d in DEGREES if d == i), *islice(DEGREES, 12)]

#  f(90) = [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

Or even using [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) (as mentioned in the comments):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, dropwhile

def f(i):
    return list(islice(dropwhile(lambda d: d != i, DEGREES), 13))
```

---

If your list is exactly as you printed above, you could also generate the slices on the fly using `range`:

```
def f(i, d=15, n=13):
    return [deg % 360 for deg in range(i, i-n*d, -d)]

# f(90) = [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

Comment: I also think OP should simply use modulo and not bother with itertools, slicing, reversing or concatening. Your one-liner is now very similar to mine, but it might be needed in order to get attention because the signal to noise is pretty low for this question. ;)

Comment: ooops. sorry, did not mean to infringe on your answer. i could remove that part or add a link to your answer. what would you prefer? (+1 anyway!)

Comment: no problem, you can leave it like this. We need to fight against 13 other answers. ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil the democratic process here seems to have taken care of it. that is reassuring!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
previous12 = [DEGREES[p-i] for p in [DEGREES.index(90)] for i in range(13)]
```

or this:

```
previous12 = (DEGREES+DEGREES[:DEGREES.index(90)+1])[:-14:-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with one slice unfortunately. You can either concatenate the pieces, which can be a bit awkward:

```
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]

index = DEGREES.index(90)
result = DEGREES[index:index - 12:-1] if index >= 12 else (DEGREES[index::-1] + DEGREES[:index - 12:-1])
print(result)
# [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285]
```

Or just use a list comprehension:

```
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]

index = DEGREES.index(90)
result = [DEGREES[i] for i in range(index, index - 12, -1)]
print(result)
# [90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `itertools.chain` might be useful here:

```
from itertools import chain

DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345
]

def get_list_of_degrees(degree, resulting_list_length):
    index = DEGREES.index(degree)
    lower_index = index - (resulting_list_length)
    if index >= resulting_list_length:
        result = DEGREES[lower_index: index]  # start 12 values back, stop at index
    else:
        result = list(chain(DEGREES[lower_index:], DEGREES[:index])) # start 12 values back, stop at index
    return result

my_degrees = get_list_of_degrees(90, 12)
print(my_degrees)
```

Yields:

> [270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75]

Which is what you specified, just backwards

Perhaps a more straightforward and scaleable/alterable method would be to generate the angles on the fly without a `DEGREES` list. Something like:

```
def get_angles(start_angle=90, increment=-15, return_array_size=12):
    angles = [i for i in range(start_angle + increment, start_angle + (return_array_size*increment) + increment, increment)]
    for index in range(len(angles)):
        while angles[index] < 0:
            angles[index] += 360
    return angles

print(get_angles())
```

Returns:

> [75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]

While allowing you the flexibility to return only 5 angles easily, or go in step sizes of 2 degrees, etc.. For instance

```
print(get_angles(increment=-2))
```

Now returns:

> [88, 86, 84, 82, 80, 78, 76, 74, 72, 70, 68, 66]

With very minimal change done to your code (otherwise you would have to generate a new `DEGREES` array to accomplish this)

Comment: The issue there is that I need the values at the end as well, so the list would pass zero and keep adding values (345, 330, etc) like it was slicing with a negative integer.

Comment: @Pygasm I misunderstood! Is this more what you were looking for?

Comment: `start_angle` should be the first element in the list. You're correct that it's possible to generate the list directly, but it's much easier with [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136669/6419007). `[i for i in something]` is just `list(something)` and can often be replaced by `something`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got empty list is because you simply don't have 12 items prior to value of 90.

What you need is a statement to handle this exception:

```
index = DEGREES.index(90)
if index >= 12:
    print(DEGREES[index-12:index])
else: 
    print(DEGREES[:index])
```

Comment: I initially put this answer, and OP said "The issue there is that I need the values at the end as well, so the list would pass zero and keep adding values (345, 330, etc) like it was slicing with a negative integer." I don't think this is suitable for OP. They specifically want to wrap around the list and get all 12 elements, instead of shortening their # of output elements

Answer (score 1):

By list slicing:

```
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]

value = 90
index = DEGREES.index(value)



result = DEGREES[:index+1][::-1] + DEGREES[index+1:][::-1]
result = result[:13]
print(result)
```

#### Output

```
[90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330,
 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

or

```
RES= [ DEGREES[i] for i in range(index,index-12-1,-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do some arithmetic.

```
index = DEGREES.index(90) + 1
offset = 12
start = index - offset
length = len(DEGREES)
print(
    list(reversed(DEGREES[max(0, start):index])) + 
    (list(reversed(DEGREES[length + start - 1 :length])))
     if start < 0
     else [])
)
```

Alternatively:

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for any number of previous values.

Just reverse the list and try `cycle()`.

```
import itertools

degrees = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345]
n=12
degrees.reverse()
ind = degrees.index(90)
degrees = degrees[ind:]+degrees[:ind]
rev_cycle = itertools.cycle(degrees)
for i in range(n+1):
    print(next(rev_cycle))
```

This is efficient as it is using generators.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the elements you wish to print out are `DEGREES[-6:6]`. You might want to add conditionals to take care of starting indexes that end up looping back around. Something like this:

```py
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]

index = DEGREES.index(90)
start_idx = index - 12
if start_idx < 0:
    print(DEGREES[start_idx:] + DEGREES[:index + 1])
else:
    print(DEGREES[start_idx:index + 1])
```

this should return the following:

```
[270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]
```

which is your solution, but reversed.

Comment: The expected output differs from the actual for this solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]


index = DEGREES.index(90)

subFront = DEGREES[:index + 1][-12:]
subFront.reverse()

remainLen = 12 - len(subFront) + 1
if remainLen > 0:
    subBack = DEGREES[-remainLen:]
    subBack.reverse()
    subFront = subFront + subBack
print(subFront)
[90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
import numpy as np

DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60,
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]
idx = DEGREES.index(90)
new_list = DEGREES[::-1]
newList = np.roll(new_list, idx+1)
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [this handy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56110167/1025391) that implements wrapping slicing. While your use case might be better solved by directly computing the angle values as other answers have already shown. This might do the trick:

```
def wrapping_slice(lst, *args):
    return [lst[i%len(lst)] for i in range(*args)]
```

Example:

```
DEGREES = [
    0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
    75, 90, 105, 120,
    135, 150, 165, 180,
    195, 210, 225, 240,
    255, 270, 285, 300,
    315, 330, 345,
]

start = DEGREES.index(90)

print(wrapping_slice(DEGREES, start, start-13, -1))
```

The output is:

```
$ python test.py
[90, 75, 60, 45, 30, 15, 0, 345, 330, 315, 300, 285, 270]
```