# How can I fix my compass application that makes a complete turn when going 359° from 0°?

Tags: swift, swiftui, 360-degrees

I am creating a compass application in swiftUI.  It works, but when I add animation to move the compass, the behavior below appears:

[image: application screen shot]

For example, when it goes from the 5° orientation to 350° it decides to do a complete turn. It is not the natural behavior for a compass.

My ContentView code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {

  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  @ObservedObject var location: LocationProvider = LocationProvider()
  @State var angle: CGFloat = 0

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      VStack {
        Rectangle()
          .frame(width: 10, height: 30)
          .background(Color(.red))
          .foregroundColor(Color(.clear))
        Spacer()
        Text(String(Double(self.location.currentHeading).stringWithoutZeroFraction) + "°")
          .font(.system(size: 40))
          .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
        Spacer()
      }
      .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
      .border(Color(.black))
      .onReceive(self.location.heading) { heading in
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
          self.angle = heading
        }
      }
      .modifier(RotationEffect(angle: self.angle))
    }.background(Color(.white))
  }
}

struct RotationEffect: GeometryEffect {
  var angle: CGFloat

  var animatableData: CGFloat {
    get { angle }
    set { angle = newValue }
  }

  func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
    return ProjectionTransform(
      CGAffineTransform(translationX: -150, y: -150)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(angle.degreesToRadians)))
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 150, y: 150))
    )
  }
}

public extension CGFloat {
  var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
  var radiansToDegrees: CGFloat { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

public extension Double {
  var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(CGFloat(self).degreesToRadians) }
  var radiansToDegrees: Double { return Double(CGFloat(self).radiansToDegrees) }

  var stringWithoutZeroFraction: String {
    return truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 ? String(format: "%.0f", self) : String(self)
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Here, I'm using the `CGAffineTransform` to rotate the compass with a matrix animation to solve the problem. I thought this would work because when I used this method in UIKit, the problem did not exist.

My LocationProvider code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine

public class LocationProvider: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {

  private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
  public let heading = PassthroughSubject<CGFloat, Never>()

  @Published var currentHeading: CGFloat {
    willSet {
      heading.send(newValue)
    }
  }

  public override init() {
    currentHeading = 0
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    super.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }

  public func updateHeading() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
  }

  public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.currentHeading = CGFloat(newHeading.trueHeading)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I like the animation! You should keep it

Comment: what is the purpose of dividing by 1? `CGFloat(round(1 * newHeading.trueHeading) / 1)`. You have also a double string initialisation `(String(String(`

Comment: Can you make the logic as follows. Instead of limiting yourself between [0-360], try to calculate the new heading as follows: `newAngle = oldAngle +/- change`. This is not the best way but is a good initial step.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136669/6419007 might help. Specifically, `(end_angle - start_angle + 180) % 360 - 180` to get the shortest rotation between two angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**: This will now work when rotating multiple times. Thanks to krjw for pointing out the issue.

There's no reason you need your `angle` property to stay within 360°. Instead of assigning `heading` to `angle` directly, calculate the difference and add it.

Here's a working example. Outside your `body` property in ContentView, add the following functions:

```
// If you ever need the current value of angle clamped to 0..<360,
//   use clampAngle(self.angle)
func clampAngle(_ angle: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    var angle = angle
    while angle < 0 {
        angle += 360
    }
    return angle.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
}

// Calculates the difference between heading and angle
func angleDiff(to heading: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return (clampAngle(heading - self.angle) + 180).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360) - 180
}
```

Then change the line that assigns `angle` to

```
self.angle += self.angleDiff(to: heading)
```

Comment: Why should it rotate multiple times?

Comment: In case you walk around in a circle. Originally, my answer didn't work if you turned in a circle multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of [John M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920937/5981293) based on the comments works, however when going into the positive direction, over 360 degrees, the animation fails again.

The simple solution would be to look for a change of -300 and smaller and then add 360 degrees. Theres is probably a better solution, but until then I will share mine:

```
.onReceive(self.location.heading) { heading in
    var diff = (heading - self.angle + 180).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360) - 180
    if diff < -300 {
        diff += 360
    }
    withAnimation {
        self.angle += diff
    }
}
```

Comment: I had also met this problem, thank you for your sharing :)

Comment: @Guillaume I think John M. answer is way more elegant and should be the accepted answer!